# Wifi in mac Book pro 15 retina

Tags: networking, wireless, macbook-pro

I need to install Ubuntu and wanted to do a dual boot but ended up losing all of my stuff on my original drive so now I can only run Ubuntu, I'm okay with that as I didn't have anything that I will miss on my old drive but now I can't use wifi and I can't seem to find any information on how to make my wifi work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)